# How to auto select the first element with ng-repeat in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

Could you please help me to auto select the first item for the menu on the left. 
here is my code : https://next.plnkr.co/edit/4pGTMsVlSiFo7eoS?preview

Comment: what do you mean by "auto select"?   Are you wanting to highlight it?   Apply styling to it?   You need to provide more information about what you are expecting.

Comment: I meant trigger click manually to select the first item on page load.

Comment: Sorry, but based on the code you have provide that seems like an odd request?   Your list on the left is currently being filtered by your "search applets" input box?   Why would you auto click a link on page load?   Do you mean you want it to auto select the first item that is display after the user searches?

Comment: Thanks man for your response, yes I want it to auto select the first item that display after the user searches and also select the first element on page load. I know it’s an odd request but that the project I am working on. I spend hours trying to figure it out but no luck. I appreciate any help you can give me or give me some advice on how to approach it?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<div class="floatingbox list">
            <input type="text" ng-model="check" placeholder="search applets"
            ng-init="setSelectedModel(model[0])">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="model in model | filter:check">
                    <a class="listItem" href ng-click='setSelectedModel(model)'>{{model.key}}</a></li>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Notice the `ng-init="setSelectedModel(model[0])` that selects the 1st item on page load by calling the same function that would be used when clicked on a certain item.

If I read what you wanted correctly.

Comment: Thanks man for your responce, but this will auto select the Applets side only and not the Categories. What i am looking for is to auto select both and apply the style like regular click

Comment: Do you know how to merge the duplicate item too, i have two performance and two investment. how can merge it into one?  Example: list two applets for performance item?